# How do I resolve an expected Ember.PromiseProxyMixin rejection?

Tags: ember.js

I ran into this odd case when I was attempting to use the `PromiseProxyMixin` to clean up my templates. One of the situations was when I had a component that rendered a list after a search is completed with our API. The searching was debounced because it triggers when the search term changes. I then wrote a cancelation mechanism that would reject the last pending promise before making a new one `this.set('promise', newPromise)`. I started noticing that these rejected promises were being spit out to our logging service because the `Ember.onerror` were trapping all *unhandled* rejections even though the Component I had *expected* that.

Normally in a promise chain you can avoid unhandled errors by making sure you place a `.catch()` at the end of the chain. However, I don't know how to do this if the promise is meant to be used in a `PromiseProxyMixin`.

Here is a [JSBin that illustrates the problem](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/susozu/2/edit?js,output) with *expected* rejections in a `PromiseProxyMixin`.

Answer (score 0):

Well as it turns out at the time of assigning the promise you can use `this.catch` to prevent the underlying promise to be *unhandled* and still set the `isRejected` and `reason` correctly:

```
this.set('promise', newPromise);
this.catch(function(err) {
  // Check if we should handle this or blow up
});
```

Here is [an example from the previous code](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/susozu/3/edit?js,output) that illustrates this.

An example might look like:

```
actions: {
  goSearch: function() {
    this.set('promise', cancellablePromise(this.get('query')));
    this.catch(function(err) {
      if (! err instanceof CancellationError) {
        throw err; // Unexpected rejection; should be considered unhandled.
      }
    });
  }
}
```